# My phone is sending messages to international number

Tags: sms

My phone is automatically sending sms to number 6592324290 and i have been charged heavily by my service provider. I don't remember that i have installed any app which can send such sms. please advice so that at lest further sms can be stopped.

Comment: Check out the link above, posted by @filoxo.  Take a look at your permissions for apps that can send SMS.  Are you rooted?

Comment: Procedure is the same as described [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/78188/16575) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/78142/16575). Just replace the permission to check for by `SEND_SMS`.